# Want to add more space between date field

Tags: xml, xhtml, odoo, odoo-10, qweb

When I take the print of a qweb report, I want to add more space between the date field : `Day - Month - Year`

What to do ?

Current code :

```
<span t-field="o.con_date" t-field-options="{&quot;format&quot;: &quot;dd MM yyyy&quot;}"></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved the problem.
What I have done here is simple (haven't thought before).

I have seperated the `dd`, `mm` and `yyyy`.

`&#160;` is used for creating spaces between them.
If you need extra spaces, you can just add more `&#160;`

`<span t-field="o.con_date" t-field-options="{&quot;format&quot;: &quot;dd &quot;}"/>&#160;<span t-field="o.con_date" t-field-options="{&quot;format&quot;: &quot;MM &quot;}"/>&#160;<span t-field="o.con_date" t-field-options="{&quot;format&quot;: &quot;yyyy &quot;}"/>&#160;`